# Javascript reload interrupts cookie deletion

Tags: javascript

So I'm using CodeIgniter framework to logout the user with the javascript below:

```
//If logged in:
$('#logout').click(function() {
    $.ajax({url:'/auth/logout',
        success: function(data){
            $('#navigation').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            document.write(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    location.reload(true);
});
```

As long as I comment out location.reload(true);, this code successfully calls the auth/logout function and logs the user out, which can be seen when I manually refresh the page.  However, with the reload active the cookie doesn't get deleted and the user stays logged in. How can I make sure the cookie is deleted before reloading the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the reload inside the success function like this:

```
$.ajax({url:'/auth/logout',
    success: function(data){
        $('#navigation').html(data);
        location.reload(true);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        document.write(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

You are reloading the page synchronically while the request is asynchronous, meaning the reload is happening before the AJAX is complete.